# PostgreSQL Full Text Search case study?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is there any case study available of any project that uses PostgreSQL 8.3+ Full Text Search on a large amount of data?

Comment: What about [this](https://www.lateral.io/resources-blog/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your definition is of a large one.

There's some data about search.postgresql.org which uses it, available [here](http://www.hagander.net/talks/Creating%20search.postgresql.org.pdf).